# What is a random intercept model?

Tags: r

I'm new to R. I have a data set

```
             df <- structure(list(schoolid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                 score = c(0L, 10L, 0L, 40L, 42L, 4L),
                 gender = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)),
            .Names = c("schoolid", "score", "gender"),
            row.names = c(NA, 6L),
            class = "data.frame")
```

for which I have to run a random intercept model to see if there is an impact of the gender on the score across schools. Can anyone kindly explain what is expected from me?

Comment: (1) I assume this is a subset of your data (you can't do a random intercept model with data from only one school); (2) it's not clear whether you want someone to explain what a random intercept model is, or whether you know what a random intercept model is and you want someone to tell you how to run it.  The former question would be appropriate on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com). If this is homework and you are stuck at this level, it seems more appropriate to go get more help from your instructor ...

Comment: Dear Ben, Thanks for your reply. I actually need the explaining, how to run it is secondary. I'm not after having a the code without knowing what I'm doing.